# pdf contains unknown characters

Tags: ios, ios5, pdf, ios6, pdf-generation

i have generated PDF in my application , there is a issue in iOS 6 (**some irrelevant characters are showing** ) , when i am generating the PDF & the same code works fine for the previos versions of iOS 5 & iOS 4.3 
I am not able to understand how to resolve , if any one know kindly resolve the issue , if you require any code snippet then leave a comment . 
The issue is depicted in the pic shown. [image]

Thanks . :)

Comment: Please also supply a sample PDF in both versions, i.e. once generated in iOS 5 and once in iOS 6, to inspect.

Comment: Are you extracting the column headers from a DB? Or how are the defined in the code?

Comment: headers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Link Code", @"Description", @"Total Bags", @"￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼Price/Bag (in $)", @"￼￼￼￼Total Price (in $)", nil];

[_myMutableAraay addObject:headers];                                        and mkl right now i dnt have pdf will try to upload soon .

Comment: According to your comment *headers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Link Code", @"Description", @"Total Bags", @"￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼Price/Bag (in $)", @"￼￼￼￼Total Price (in $)", nil];* you do have those irrelevant characters in your column headers. It looks like iOS 6 takes you serious and works correctly while iOS 5 censored your inputs and so kind of failed...

Comment: Hhmmm that's funny. In the internet explorer on windows i saw those extra characters in your code line and in my quoting it, but on my mobile phone i don't...

Comment: well thank you so much for showing concern for my issue , i just re-wrote the same content and OMG it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already meantioned in the comments to your question, you actually have the irrelevant characters in your `headers` definition:

[image]

On the other hand, when viewing those comments on my mobile phone I saw an hour ago:

[image]

Thus, you probably don't see those characters in your code either. I would propose retyping the whole strings "Price/Bag (in $)" and "Total Price (in $)" in your code and compiling again.

Comment: dude you are awesome, i was dam worried what to do and how to resolve , but i never thought the solution was that much easy , i just re wrote the content and it worked perfectly .. Thanks a Ton !!! :)